# Can we use these Secure Configuration Properties to access the encrypted values defined in app.properties in Mule?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, properties-file

I know that we can access the encrypted values in externalized.yaml or.property files declared in the resource folder using the Secure Configuration Properties.

as like same, is it able to access the encrypted values if I defined in the app.properties using this Secure Configuration Properties?

I could able to access the values in loca.properties which is inside the src/main/resource folder using Secure Configuration Properties ?

[image]

Just curious to know is it works in app.properties.

Comment: What's app.properties? Another file in your application?

Comment: in mule 3, we have app.properties in src/main/mule

Comment: I'm guessing you refer to `src/main/app/mule-app.properties`. Any other property file is custom of your application. `src/main/mule` is only for Mule 4 applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mule 3.x there is a file src/main/app/mule-app.properties that is used to define some default properties. That file is just not supported in Mule 4.x. You need to explicitly define normal [configuration property](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/configuring-properties#properties-files) files with the built-in `<configuration-properties>` or encrypted ones with the [Secure Configuration Properties Module](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/com.mulesoft.modules/mule-secure-configuration-property-module/) which you seem to be using. In both cases you need to create your properties files and reference them explicitly.